# Unable to retrieve new customer from MYOB SDK

Tags: c#, myob

I am trying something like

```
customer.Uid = Guid.NewGuid()
// set other properties
myCustomerService.Insert(myCompanyFile, myobCustomerContact, myCredentials );
myobCustomerContact = myCustomerService.Get(myCompanyFile, myobCustomerContact.UID,myCredentials);
```

The Get returns a 404 error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Shaun-Wilde  can  you help?

Comment: investigating https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818493.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This question was originally using await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot currently control the UID used to insert a new entity; the API will create a new UID on insert for you.

When you use `InsertAsync` the task will return a string which is the full URI to the newly inserted entity. You can then retrieve the entity using

```
var location = await service.InsertAsync(cf, customer, credentials, ct);
var insertedEntity = await service.GetAsync(cf, new Uri(location), credentials, ct);
```

however if you want to insert and retrieve an inserted entity then you can use `InsertExAsync` e.g.

```
var insertEntity = await service.InsertExAsync(cf, customer, credentials, ct);
```

Comment: Thanks Shaun, in your 2 line answer,  how does the 2nd await "know" to wait for the location to be populated?

Comment: @kirsteng - it's a single call - it tells the API to return the full body of the inserted entity in the response

Comment: But the following is 2 calls

var location = await service.InsertAsync(cf, customer, credentials, ct);
var insertedEntity = await service.GetAsync(cf, new Uri(location), credentials, ct);  

How does the 2nd await necessarily "know" the location? since it may execute before the first await has returned.

Comment: That is with InsertExAsync there is only one call. However in the scenario where there is a call to InsertAsync followed by GetAsync there is 2 calls, and the 2nd one needs the location from the first... I am wondering how that works?

Comment: The `await` causes it to wait; the 2nd call does not happen until the first has completed.